# Errors in jQuery ajax are not getting reported

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, handler

I'm having difficulty with the jQuery ajax success handler. Any javascript run-time errors that occur in the success handler dont seem to be getting reported (no errors appear in the Firefox error console). And trying to debug without error notification is driving me crazy. Could someone take a look at the simplified version of my code below and let me know if I'm doing something stupid that might be causing the problem.

If not, if someone could test this in Firefox and confirm (or not) that no error messages appear and its not just me going mad (or there is something wrong with my Firefox installation or something). I've also put the code on the web - so you can just click below to test it ....

http://www.alisonstrachan.co.uk/tests/ajax2/ajax_test2.html

**ajax_test2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    //alert(missingVariable1);           //uncomment -> get error reported (as expected)

    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_test2_process.php",
        data: {send: "hello"},
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            $("#results").append(data);
            alert(missingVariable2);     //no error reported (there should be surely?)
            $("#results").append(" finished ");
            }
        });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**ajax_test2_process.php**

```
<?php
    echo "received: " . $_REQUEST['send'];
?>
```

Comment: the page to which you redirected is displaying `received:hello` isn't it the intended result

Comment: @3nigma Thanks for testing this out. Yes this is the intended result. But what I need to know is what do you get in the Firefox error console. Is the deliberate 'alert()' error being loged in your console?

Comment: maybe the ajax request fails, thus success is never called, try to change success with complete, use FIREBUG

Comment: @3nigma: It should also append "finished", which it is not due to the alert [silently] failing.

Comment: Thanks @max4ever. The ajax success handler is getting called because I see "received: hello" on the page. I have also tried Firebug and it too does not report the error in its console tab.

Comment: I also get 'received:hello'. You might take a look at [blackbird js](http://www.gscottolson.com/blackbirdjs/) and use 'log.debug("got here")'

Comment: @Brad Christie Ah! i missed the obvious...

Comment: @Eonasdan, max4ever, 3nigma Please can you tell me if you see the error getting reported or if its silent.

Comment: @macrae_dj  nope i didn't see any error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's silently failing due to jQuery [wrapping the callback in a try...catch](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L542-550).

So, put simply, any errors or bad code found within a callback function will just silently fail out (and bubble up to the try...catch I've outlined) then halt processing where it lies.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. But surely this makes debugging a nightmare. Or is there a better way to debug. Am I missing something?

Comment: @macrae_dj: Maybe place a `console.log('ajax complete');` at the bottom of the callback to validate the callback has executed in its entirety? I usually go on the basis that everything I wanted done looks like it's performed (good call) or check for any absence of action (bad call).

Comment: In my real project I have a huge amount of javascript in the success callback. I'm trying to figure out how to 'jump out' of the try/catch as I really need to be able to debug. I though maybe using a `setTimeout(continueSuccessHandler, 1)` or something. Dont know if there is any thing more elegant?

Comment: @macrae again, as far as debug take a look at the blackbird js. It's great for debugging your code and no annoying alert boxes!

Comment: @Eonasdan. The issue is that run-time javascript errors are not getting reported. I can still debug - but I'm reduced to using Firebug's console.log() to try and figure out where its going wrong - and this is a crude debugging scheme compared to getting told explicitly where the error is occurring. Thanks for the blackbird link though, could come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to Adblock Plus or a similar extension (check the extensions that you have installed), see [bug 653533](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=653533).

Comment: I get the same result when running Firefox in safe mode (all extensions dissabled).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the other call backs for the Ajax function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - you might want to take a look at `error` and also `statusCode` - Firebug is also very useful for investigating ajax related issues - you can see the post and response for an ajax communication.

If you want to log to the firebug console use `console.log('text');`

Answer (score 0):

you could also try wrapping your ajax in an object like the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) suggests:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({ url: "example.php" })
    .success(function() { alert("success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```